# How to parse a slash delimited column and create new columns within the same file, using unix or R?

Tags: r, perl, unix, awk

The first column of my file is delimited by forward slash in most of the rows but not in all. I want to parse the first column, creating new columns within the same file. (I need the first field within the first column, so if there is a way to just print the first field in a new column within the same file, that would be fine, too). The number of columns are not the same for all rows. The patterns of other columns are more complex.
Input:

```
SAMD11/SAMD11    chr1    ALLELEA=T    taWT=1    TOP=+
SAMD11/SAMD11/NOC2L    chr1    ALLELEA=T    taPN=-1 
AGRN    chr1    ALLELEA=T
```

Desired output:

```
SAMD11  SAMD11    chr1    ALLELEA=T    taWT=1    TOP=+
SAMD11  SAMD11    NOC2L   chr1     ALLELEA=T     taPN=-1
AGRN    chr1      ALLELEA=T
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: have a look at '?read.table' and look at the `sep=...` argument.

Comment: what have you tried? stackoverflow isn't for doing your homework/job, eg. we don't accept specs and output code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this: awk -F"/"  '{print $1}' filename. but I don't know how to create the new column within the original file.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate fields with slash (`FS = "/"`) and set a tabulator to separate fields in output (`OFS = "\t"`). You must do any kind of dummy process, `$1 = $1` in my case, to make `awk` convert from one mode to the other one. I assume that there is no other slash out of first field.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/"; OFS = "\t" } { $1 = $1; print }' infile
```

It yields:

```
SAMD11  SAMD11    chr1    ALLELEA=T    taWT=1    TOP=+
SAMD11  SAMD11  NOC2L    chr1    ALLELEA=T    taPN=-1 
AGRN    chr1    ALLELEA=T
```

---

**EDIT** for a script that takes into account the option of slashes in many fields. It checks if first field has a slash and removes them with a tab. The output is the same as before.

```
awk '
  BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } 
  $1 ~ /\// { 
    gsub( /\//, "\t", $1 ) 
  } 
  { print }
' infile
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to mention that there are slashes in the other columns as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit. But, still the parsed fields are printed in the adjacent columns and not in "new" columns; the number of fields are not the same in the first column, and therefore the other columns become disorganized.